# First Order Phase Transition - Heat Capacity

Tags: thermodynamics

[image: (a) First Order (b) Second Order]

At constant pressure :

$\frac{dH}{dT}=C_p $

Hence, why doesn't the graph of $C_p$ against $T$ show two perfectly horizontal lines (with the obvious discontinuity) ?

I mean the gradient of $H$ versus $T$ graph is constant so the $C_p$ value should be constant as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific heat capacity does change with temperature, in fact famously [going to zero at absolute zero](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/debye.html).

Aside from the low temperature behavior, I would view a specific heat capacity increasing with temperature as the substance acheiving greater degrees of freedom as temperature increased.

In any case, the graph is correct that specific heat capacities are temperature dependent, and it would be misleading to draw the graph as if they weren't.

Answer (score 1):

The questioner is right: although there is nothing intrinsically wrong with the displayed $C_p(T)$ curve, $C_p$ should not vary if $\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_p$ is constant. Given the illustrated temperature dependence of $C_p$, the $H(T)$ curve should have perceivable curvature.

Comment: I'd like to add that every reasonable textbook and online source has the exact same graphs as those above. This includes Atkins Physical Chemistry and other university lecture handouts.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I think this is better suited as a comment rather than an answer.